# Best practice for heading levels

Tags: html, html-heading

I have a group of pages wherein one page has subcategories and another page doesn't. What's the best way to structure the headings? Should each item of the same importance have the same heading level, even if that means skipping h2, for example? That route certainly makes CSS easier.

First page:

```
<h1>Dogs</h1>
<h2>Small Dogs</h2>
<h3>Chihuahua</h3>
<h3>Jack Russell Terrier</h3>
<h2>Big Dogs</h2>
<h3>Greyhound</h3>
<h3>Golden Retriever</h3>
```

Second page:

```
<h1>Cats</h1>
<h3>American Shorthair</h3>
<h3>Siamese</h3>
<h3>Manx</h3>
```

(Also assume actual content under each h3, ofc.)

Or should the dog breeds be h2 and the cat breeds be h3? Or should each breed in this example be the h2, and not mark up "Small Dogs" and "Big Dogs" as headings at all? Or some other option?

Comment: Things like this are typically up to the developer (you). Whatever style you think fits your webpage the best.

Comment: If Search Engine traffic is important to you, you'll probably want to search for "google seo headings" or something to that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing like this is dependent on developer/designer how you want to do things. The general concept about heading is that

> The most important tag is the h1 heading tag, and will usually be
>   the title of a post.And the sub headings go to the h2 tag and the order goes so on.

This things I mentioned are based on the importance given to the SEO (Search Engine Optimization). Generally a page should contain only one h1 tag whereas there may be several h2 tags.
Now to simplify things the main thing is what you want to do. Best way to achieve is use h2 and h3 more and use class to give the proper style. But remember don't use h1 tag more than once in your page. According to the SEO general way

> The h1 tag should contain your targeted keywords, ones that closely
>   relate to the page title and are relevant to your content. The h2 tag
>   is a subheading and  should contain similar keywords to your h1 tag.
>   Your h3 is then a subheading for your h2 and so on. Think of them as a
>   hierarchy based on importance, the above being more important than the
>   below.

The main thing is what do you think is the order of preferences that these lists go on. Which is more important and which is less. And after h3 tags they generally don't matter so use classes and style them.

Answer (score 0):

We should always use h1 tag with the main keywords. H1 tags should be used only one. 
Then we can use H2 along the keywords. Should be used as subheading.

Then h3 and h4.